# Is there a way to compare columns in two dataframes with varying column numbers and removing rows that don't match a certain column?

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes: `all_species` (155 obs, 1 var) and `all_taxa` (33124 obs, 8 variables). What I want to do is find the observation present in `all_species$species` column in the `all_taxa$species` column and only keep those observations in the `all_taxa` dataframe resulting in 155 obs of 8 variables.

What I've done so far is create 2 vectors:

```
species_vector_2 <- as.vector(all_species$Species)
all_taxa_vector <- as.vector(all_taxa $Species)
```

Then I have used the following code to determine if `species_vector_2` is present in `all_taxa_vector`:

```
all_taxa %in% species_vector_2
```

The output gives me a long list of `TRUE` or `FALSE` values. What I want is to remove the `FALSE` values from the `all_taxa` dataframe. So I tried to index the dataframe:

```
all_taxa[(all_taxa_vector %in% species_vector_2)]
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error: Length of logical index vector for `[` must equal number of columns (or 1):
* `.data` has 8 columns
* Index vector has length 33124
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

So my question is, is there any way to index this based on the specific column I want indexed (`all_taxa$species`).

The ideal solution would result in the `all_taxa` dataframe to ONLY include the species from `all_species$species`, while retaining the other variables present in `all_taxa`. Thus `all_taxa` would have 155 observations and 8 variables.

`all_species` dataframe

```
                 Species
1         Ichthyomyzon castaneus
2            Ichthyomyzon fossor
3         Ichthyomyzon unicuspis
4           Lethenteron appendix
5             Petromyzon marinus
6           Oreochromis niloticus
```

`all_taxa` dataframe

```
SpecCode Species                 Genus        Subfamily           Family        Order       Class         SuperClass 
     <dbl> <chr>                   <chr>        <chr>               <chr>         <chr>       <chr>         <chr>      
1        2 Oreochromis niloticus   Oreochromis  Pseudocrenilabrinae Cichlidae     Perciformes Actinopteryg~ Osteichthy~
2        3 Oreochromis mossambicus Oreochromis  Pseudocrenilabrinae Cichlidae     Perciformes Actinopteryg~ Osteichthy~
3        4 Engraulis ringens       Engraulis    Engraulinae         Engraulidae   Clupeiform~ Actinopteryg~ Osteichthy~
4        5 Orthopristis chrysopte~ Orthopristis Haemulinae          Haemulidae    Perciformes Actinopteryg~ Osteichthy~
5        6 Coryphaena hippurus     Coryphaena   NA                  Coryphaenidae Perciformes Actinopteryg~ Osteichthy~
6        7 Coryphaena equiselis    Coryphaena   NA                  Coryphaenidae Perciformes Actinopteryg~ Osteichthy~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to know for sure without reproducible datasets, but I think this should work:

```r
library("tidyverse")

all_taxa %>% 
    filter(species %in% unique(all_species$species))
```